# PowerShell script ignores files with <whitespace>H

Tags: powershell

I inherited this script from my precursor, which is supposed to copy a bunch of files from one location into a JFrog Artifactory.

It workes fine except for files with  followed by an `H` in the name.

For example `Test My Client.exe` will be copied correctly but `Test My Host.exe` will be ignored by the script.

Anybody has an idea what the reason for this strange behaviour is?

```
param
(
    [string]$RootPath="D:\_temp\upload\",
    [string]$Repo="repo-snapshot",
    [string]$Product="SEARCHER",
    [string]$Version="1.23.45678.9012",
    [string]$ArtifactoryRoot    
)
$AF_USER = "myUser"
$AF_PWD = "pA55VVoRd" #ConvertTo-SecureString "pA55VVoRd" -AsPlainText -Force  
$CREDS = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($AF_USER, $AF_PWD)  
$MajorMinor = $Version.Split('.')[0] + "." + $Version.Split('.')[1]
$BuildRevision = $Version.Split('.')[2] + "." + $Version.Split('.')[3]
$uri = "https://artifactory.test.com/artifactory/$Repo/TEST/$Product/$MajorMinor/$BuildRevision/$ArtifactoryRoot/"
$curl = "$PSScriptRoot\..\..\bin\ReleaseU\curl.exe"
Write-Host $MajorMinor
write-host $BuildRevision

$filesToUpload = Get-ChildItem $RootPath -Recurse -File

foreach($file in $filesToUpload)
{
    $artifactoryAddPath = $file.FullName.Remove(0,$RootPath.Length).Replace('\','/')
    $completeUrl = $uri+$artifactoryAddPath
    write-host $completeUrl

    $FileSize = (Get-Item $file.FullName).Length /1MB
    Write-Host "Filesize: "$FileSize" MB"
    $preTime = Get-Date

    write-host "$curl --user $AF_USER`:$AF_PWD --upload-file " $file.FullName "$completeUrl --insecure"
    . $curl --user $AF_USER`:$AF_PWD --upload-file $file.FullName $completeUrl --insecure

    $postTime = Get-Date
    Write-Host "Upload finished"
    $timeDiff = $postTime - $preTime
    $avgSpeed = $FileSize / $timeDiff.TotalSeconds
    Write-Host -Object ("Upload speed is: {0:N2}MB/sec" -f ($avgSpeed));

}
```

Comment: assuming it's something to do with `curl` try using `Start-Process` with `-ArgumentList` instead of running it using `.` or `&` - confirm that the exact string going into `-ArgumentList` works if run on the command line outside of the script.

Comment: Try putting quotation marks around `$file.FullName` when calling `curl`.

Comment: @baconbits In addition to the quotes you'll need to wrap it in a SubExpression operator like so: `"$($file.FullName)"`

Comment: off-topic: `[string]$Version="1.23.45678.9012"; $MajorMinor = $Version.Split('.')[0]`  what? There is a version type for this task -  `[version]$Version="1.23.45678.9012"; $MajorMinor = $Version.Major + $Version.Minor; $BuildRevision = $Version.Build + $Version.Revision`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried `write-host "$curl --user $AF_USER`:$AF_PWD --upload-file " $file.FullName "$completeUrl --insecure"
    . $curl --user $AF_USER`:$AF_PWD --upload-file "$($file.FullName)" $completeUrl --insecure`
and some other variations with quotes around `$file.FullName` but the files with `<space>H` still wount be copied.
Does anyone have an idea if this could be some problem with a regex or something?